# I can't uninstall Anroid Studio

Tags: applications

So, I installed wine and then I installed Android Studio from it. The icon shows up on Applications but it does not run.

Then I removed Wine. Now, I still have that unworking icon in Applications for Android Studio that does not work. How do I remove it?

Also, is there a cleaner for Linux that helps with uninstalling unnecessary applications?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with deleting the wine android studio, but: Android Studio works fine on all ubuntu derivates (like elementary os). For installation see this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

As GDog says, Android Studio works fine natively on Elementary OS and you don't need wine.

To remove the existing icon you need to look for .desktop file with a matching name and remove it. This can be done via the terminal - .desktop files are usually found in /usr/share/applications/ If you want to do it via a GUI then grab AppEdit from the AppStore and find and delete the details in there.